# An inequality involving sums of squares and sums of cubes

Tags: inequalities, sums-of-squares

Assume that we have $m$ real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_m\in[0,1/4]$ satisfying the following equations:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^m x_i=a_1, \sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2=a_2,\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^3\geq a_3,$$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are all positive. The aim is to obtain restrictions on $a_1,a_2,a_3$. We can consider the polynomial 
$$f_b(x)=(x-1/4)(x+b)^2=x^3+(2b-1/4)x^2+(b^2-b/2)x-(1/4)b^2$$
 where $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$0\geq \sum_{i=1}^m f_b(x_i)\geq a_3+(2b-1/4)a_2+(b^2-b/2)a_1-(1/4)b^2m,$$ where the right hand side can be seen as a quadratic polynomial in variable $b$ and it is always less than or equal to 0. This will give us a restriction on $a_1,a_2,a_3$. I wonder whether there are other restrictions on $a_1,a_2,a_3$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^3\ge a_3$ instead of $\sum_{i=3}^m x_i^3\ge a_3$? If yes, do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^3 = a_3$ instead of $\sum_{i13}^m x_i^3 \ge a_3$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It should be $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^3\geq a_3$.

Comment: Then $a_3$ may be equal to 0, and we do not have $a_2^2\le a_1a_3$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov you are right. The argument $a_2^2\leq a_1a_3$ is a stupid mistake. Why $a_3$ may be equal to $0$?

Comment: @SihuangHu why not? $a_3=0$ always satisfies your restriction.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I see. I extract those (in)equalities from spherical $4$-designs, and in general $a_1,a_2,a_3$ should be all positive.

Comment: $f_b$ is nonpositive for $x\leq \frac{1}{4}$ so the sum will be nonpositive

Comment: @user100927 Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. If it is correct, I can proceed.

Let $m \ge 3$ be a fixed positive integer. Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$
be the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

First, let us prove the following lemma.

Lemma 1: There exists $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m \in [0, \frac{1}{4}]$, not all zero, such
that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = a_1, \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_m^2 = a_2$ and $x_1^3+x_2^3 + \cdots + x_m^3 
\ge a_3$,

if and only if,
\begin{equation}
0 < a_1 \le \frac{m}{4}, \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_1^2}{m} \le a_2 \le \frac{1}{16}\lfloor 4a_1\rfloor + \left(a_1 - \frac{1}{4}\lfloor 4a_1\rfloor\right)^2, \qquad (2)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
a_3 \le F(a_1, a_2),\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad (3)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
F(a_1, a_2) =  &\max_{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m} \ x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \cdots + x_m^3\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad (4)\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\quad x_i\in [0, \frac{1}{4}], \forall i; \ x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = a_1, \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_m^2 = a_2.\nonumber
\end{align}

Proof of Lemma 1: WLOG, assume that $x_1 \ge x_2\ge \cdots \ge x_m$.

**(the "only if" part)**:

i) Clearly, $0 < a_1 \le \frac{m}{4}$.

ii) Given $0 < a_1 \le \frac{m}{4}$, the range of $a_2$ is $[g(a_1), f(a_1)]$ where
\begin{align*}
f(a_1) = &\max_{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m} \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_m^2\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\quad x_i\in [0, \frac{1}{4}], \forall i; \ x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = a_1
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
g(a_1) = &\min_{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m} \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_m^2\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\quad x_i\in [0, \frac{1}{4}], \forall i; \ x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = a_1.
\end{align*}
It is easy to obtain $g(a_1) = \frac{a_1^2}{m}$ (the minimum is attained always when $x_1=x_2 = \cdots = x_m = \frac{a_1}{m}\in [0, \frac{1}{4}]$).

We have $f(a_1) = \frac{1}{16}\lfloor 4a_1\rfloor + \left(a_1 - \frac{1}{4}\lfloor 4a_1\rfloor\right)^2$ since
$h(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ is convex, and (denote $K = \lfloor 4a_1\rfloor$)

$\big(\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \cdots, \frac{1}{4}}_{K}, a_1 - \frac{1}{4}K, 0, 0, \cdots, 0\big)$ majorizes $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m)$ with
$x_i\in [0, \frac{1}{4}], \forall i; \ x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = a_1$.

iii) Clearly, (3) is true.

**(the "if" part)**: It is clear according to the **(the "only if" part)**. This completes the proof of Lemma 1.

Let us proceed. We want to find the explicit expression of $F(a_1, a_2)$.

Let $(x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m)$ be the global maximizer of the optimization problem given in (4).
We claim that $|\{x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m\}|\le 4$ where $|\cdot|$ is the cardinality of a set.

Proof of the claim: Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $|\{x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m\}| > 4$.
WLOG, assume that $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \frac{1}{4}.$
Denote $D = 16(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) - 32(x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3) + 8(x_1+x_2+x_3) -3.$

Remark: The proof of the inequalities in this part is simple and thus omitted.

1) If $D\le 0$, let
$$a = \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_1x_3-x_2x_3}\, ,$$
$$b = \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_1x_3-x_2x_3}\, .$$
We have $x_1+x_2+x_3 = a + a + b, \ x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = a^2 + a^2 + b^2$ and $0 \le a \le b\le \frac{1}{4}$.
Thus, $(a, a, b, x_4, x_5, \cdots, x_m)$ is a feasible point of the optimization problem given in (4).
We also have $a^3 + a^3 + b^3 > (x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^2) \Longleftarrow (x_2-x_3)^2(x_1-x_3)^2(x_1-x_2)^2 > 0.$
Thus, we have $a^3 + a^3 + b^3 + x_4^3 + x_5^3 + \cdots + x_m^3 > x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 + x_4^3 + x_5^3 + \cdots + x_m^3.$
Thus, $(a, a, b, x_4, x_5, \cdots, x_m)$ is strictly better than $(x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m)$.
This contradicts the optimality of $(x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m)$.

2) If $D > 0$, let
$$u = \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{2} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{D}\,,$$
$$v = \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{2} - \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{D}\,.$$
We have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = \frac{1}{4} + u + v, \ x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = (\frac{1}{4})^2 + u^2 + v^2.$
It follows from $D>0$ and $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \frac{1}{4}$ that
$$x_1+x_2+x_3\ge \frac{1}{4},$$
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \ge \frac{1}{16},$$
$$16(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3) - 4(x_1+x_2+x_3) + 1\ge 0,$$
$$16(x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3) - 8(x_1+x_2+x_3) + 3 > 0,$$
$$-192x_1x_2x_3 + 48(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3) - 12(x_1+x_2+x_3) + 3 > 0.$$
With these facts, we have $0 \le v \le u \le \frac{1}{4}$ and $(\frac{1}{4})^3 + u^3 + v^3 > x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3.$
Thus, $(\frac{1}{4}, u, v, x_4, x_5, \cdots, x_m)$ is a feasible point of the optimization problem given in (4)
and is strictly better than $(x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m)$.
This contradicts the optimality of $(x_1, \ x_2, \cdots, x_m)$. This completes the proof of the claim.

Comment: I agree with Lemma 1. Could you please explain how do you apply the KKT condition and get the conclusion that $|\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m\}|\le 4$?

Comment: I updated my answer. I proved it without the KKT conditions.